# classic ASP using JavaScript gives a 500 error

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic, iis-7.5, serverside-javascript

I can't figure out why I keep getting an `HTTP/1.1 500 Server Error` but only when using JavaScript as the server-side language. If I use VBScript it works just fine. I have other sites running on the same machine using server-side JavaScript with no problem. I can't seem to find any more information through the event viewer, the IIS logs or searching the web.

Below I have small code sample in VBScript as well as in JavaScript.

### VBScript (works):

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>
<% Response.Write("hello vbscript") %>
```

### JavaScript (500 error):

```
<%@ Language=JavaScript %>
<% Response.Write("hello javascript"); %>
```

I'm sure that this a configuration problem but I can't seem to find anything even remotely pertaining to this issue.

Comment: enable `Turn off HTTP Friendly Errors` in your browser (under internet options, advanced) and see if you get a more detailed error message.

Comment: Tried that. doesn't work on this particular problem.

Comment: Cheers for getting it solved! Please write the solution as a new answer and mark it as accepted, then remove from the question. That's how things work here. Thanks!

Comment: If you want decent error messages, as well as disabling Friendly HTTP Error Messages, you need to go into IIS Manager, go to your website, in the ASP section go to: Compilation > Debugging Properties > Send Errors to Browser = True. This should make them a little more helpful:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much aging and pulling out my hair, the problem was that javascript requires 32-bit applications. If you right click on application pool in question and set "Enable 32-bit Applications" to True, everything works. As figured, it was a configuration issue but the docs and error message, or rather lack of error messages, left a lot to be desired.